# Inserting values into JS scripts using python

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x

I am parsing JS files stored in a directory to fetch out the values inside `tags`. Upon finding relevant values in the `tags` using regex, I want to move those values under a new section called `controls`. I have been able to get the required values in the `controls` variable using the script below:

```
def parse_sigs(target_folder):    
    try:
        count = 0

        for root, dir, files in os.walk(target_folder):
            for file in files:
                file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
                if file_extension.lower() == ".js":
                    print(file)
                    filename = os.path.join(root, file)
                    print(f'Processing : {filename}')

                    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
                        data = f_in.read()
                    data = re.search(r"\btags\s*:\s*(\[.*?\])", data, flags=re.S)
                    if data:
                        data = literal_eval(data.group(1))
                        #print(type(data)
                        cregex = re.compile(r".*\-.*\-.*[\.|\-].*")
                        controls = list(filter(cregex.match, data))
                            
                        count +=1
                        print(controls)
        print(count)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in Processing  {filename} Skipping -- ")  
        print(e)
```

I am not able to think of a way to now insert the `controls` list as a new field into the JS file and update it. It should appear after the `tags` field.

An example JS file looks like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')
const remediation = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../sig/file.md'), 'utf-8')

module.exports = {
  status: "ENABLED",
  sig: {
    name: "iam",
    tags: [
        "aws",
        "iam",
        "compliance",
        "chg-02.1",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.12",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.14",
        "SOC-2",
        "SOC-2-CC6.8",
        "NIST-800-53rev5",
        "NIST-800-53rev5-CM-3(1)"
    ],
    result: "A.id, A.name",
    result_header: [
      "account_id",
      "account_name",
    ],
    primary_resource: "user_arn",
  },
  expected: {
   "all":
    [
      {
        user_name: "2506"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My end goal is to create a JS file whose `tags` and newly added `controls` section looks like this:

```
    tags: [
        "aws",
        "iam",
        "compliance",
        "chg-02.1",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4",
        "SOC-2",
        "NIST-800-53rev5"
    ],

controls: [
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.12",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.14",
        "NIST-800-53rev5-CM-3(1)",
        "SOC-2-CC6.8",
    ],
```

Edit:
Able to get it working with the solution provided by @Dan-Dev.
The only thing which is still out of place is the closing `]`. Is there a way to fix the closing bracket to indent correctly?

```
    tags: [
        "aws",
        "docdb",
        "kms",
        "configuration-check",
],
 controls: [
        "SOC-2-CC6.1",
        "NIST-800-53rev5-SC-12"
]
```

Comment: Is there a comma after `status: "ENABLED"` or is it invalid JavaScript?

Comment: maybe find position of string `tags :` in text with code, next find position of first `]` after `tags :` and later use this position to split text and instert `control` - something like this: `text[:position] + ", control: [....]" + text[position:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the tags and convert them to JSON using the package `jsonnet` iterate over them using your regex then build a string to replace the original tags like this:

```
import json
import os
import re
import _jsonnet


def parse_sigs(target_folder):
    
    count = 0
    cregex = re.compile(r".*-.*-.*[.|\-].*")
    for root, _, files in os.walk(target_folder):
        for file in files:
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

            if file_extension.lower() == ".js":
                new_tags = []
                controls = []
                # pint(file)

                filename = os.path.join(root, file)
                print(f'Processing : {filename}')
                try:
                    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
                        data = f_in.read()
                        snippet = re.findall(r'module.exports = (.*);', data, flags=re.S)[0]
                    json_data = json.loads(_jsonnet.evaluate_snippet('snippet', snippet))

                    # print(json.dumps(json_data['sig']['tags'], indent=4))
                    for tag in json_data['sig']['tags']:
                        if re.match(cregex, tag):
                            controls.append(tag)
                        else:
                            new_tags.append(tag)
                    new_string = f"tags: {json.dumps(new_tags, indent=8)},\n controls: {json.dumps(controls, indent=8)}"

                    data = re.sub(r'tags: \[(.*?)]', new_string, data, flags=re.S)
                    
                    if data:
                        print(data)
                        count += 1
                    print(count)
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error in Processing  {filename} Skipping -- ")
                    print(e)


parse_sigs('./')
```

Outputs:

```
Processing : ./test.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')
const remediation = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../sig/file.md'), 'utf-8')

module.exports = {
  status: "ENABLED",
  sig: {
    name: "iam",
    tags: [
        "aws",
        "iam",
        "compliance",
        "chg-02.1",
        "SOC-2",
        "NIST-800-53rev5"
],
 controls: [
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.12",
        "AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.14",
        "SOC-2-CC6.8",
        "NIST-800-53rev5-CM-3(1)"
],
    result: "A.id, A.name",
    result_header: [
      "account_id",
      "account_name",
    ],
    primary_resource: "user_arn",
  },
  expected: {
   "all":
    [
      {
        user_name: "2506"
      }
    ]
  }
};


1
```

UPDATED WITH FORMATTING:

```
import json
import os
import re
import _jsonnet
import jsbeautifier


opts = jsbeautifier.default_options()
opts.indent_size = 2
opts.space_in_empty_paren = True


def parse_sigs(target_folder):
    count = 0
    cregex = re.compile(r".*-.*-.*[.|\-].*")
    for root, _, files in os.walk(target_folder):
        for file in files:
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

            if file_extension.lower() == ".js":
                new_tags = []
                controls = []
                # pint(file)

                filename = os.path.join(root, file)
                print(f'Processing : {filename}')
                try:
                    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
                        data = f_in.read()
                        snippet = re.findall(r'module.exports = (.*);', data, flags=re.S)[0]
                    json_data = json.loads(_jsonnet.evaluate_snippet('snippet', snippet))

                    # print(json.dumps(json_data['sig']['tags'], indent=4))
                    for tag in json_data['sig']['tags']:
                        if re.match(cregex, tag):
                            controls.append(tag)
                        else:
                            new_tags.append(tag)
                    new_string = f"tags: {json.dumps(new_tags, indent=8)},\n controls: {json.dumps(controls, indent=8)}"

                    data = re.sub(r'tags: \[(.*?)]', new_string, data, flags=re.S)

                    data = jsbeautifier.beautify(data, opts)

                    if data:
                        print(data)
                        count += 1
                    print(count)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error in Processing  {filename} Skipping -- ")
                    print(e)


parse_sigs('./')
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working well. I am now trying to write the change to the file. the formatting seems to be getting messed up. All I am doing is doing a `f.write(data)`. Is there anything else I should be doing to have the changes written to the file as well?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. the only thing which is still out of place is the closing `]`. Is there a way to fix the closing bracket to indent correctly? I have added the example in the Edit section above. Thanks for the help!! Very helpful.

Comment: to format it `import jsbeautifier`
`print(jsbeautifier.beautify(data))` you can give it options too as a second argument see https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: I added the full code to my answer you may want to play around with the options

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer and/or vote for it if it answered your question :)

Comment: definitely helpful. Thanks for that.

Comment: For some of the files I have, I am seeing this error. Any idea how it can be fixed.
RuntimeError: STATIC ERROR: snippet:70:16: expected token OPERATOR but got ","
The error occurs on:
                    json_data = json.loads(_jsonnet.evaluate_snippet('snippet', snippet))

Comment: is the JavaScript valid or does the regular expression need adjusting or you may have to strip a trailing comma maybe try debugging or printing the extracted values

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve it. Another issue I am landing into is, if the controls tag already exists, can we update the existing one instead of creating a new one. I tried a few things but it recreates the control tag twice if I run it on a file already having the control section. This doesn't happen with the tags section. Can you please suggest a change.

Comment: `controls = json_data['sig']['controls'] if controls in json_data['sig'] else controls` should work then use a re.sub to replace the original controls tag with an empty string

Comment: Not able to get it to work. I am mostly ending up overwriting and losing the existing tags in controls.